# Remove punctuation marks except apostrophe Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

`preg_replace ("/(\p{P})/", ' ', $str)` removes apostrophes, and it should not. Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\p{P}(?<!')/
```

The additional look-behind assertion is to ensure that the punctuation character is not an apostrophe.